# Show/hide sublayers, QGIS API C++

Tags: qgis, api, c++

I'm loading .osm map using QGIS API C++ 3.22.4.

The map has several sublayers (points, lines, multilinestrings...)
I'm trying to switch on/off sublayers with setSubLayerVisibility(), but always getting loaded the first layer (points).

How can I show specific layer(s) and hide others?

```
void MainWindow::addLayerOSM() {

    QString myFileNameVect = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"),
                                                          QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath(), tr("*.osm"));
    openLayerOSM(myFileNameVect);
}


void MainWindow::openLayerOSM(QString myFileNameVect){

    QFileInfo myVectorFileInfo(myFileNameVect);
    QgsVectorLayer * myVectorLayer = new QgsVectorLayer(myVectorFileInfo.filePath(),
                                                        myVectorFileInfo.completeBaseName());
    if (myVectorLayer->isValid()){
        auto provider = myVectorLayer->dataProvider();
        auto subLayers = provider->subLayers();

        for (int i = 0; i < subLayers.size(); ++i) {
            auto name = subLayers.at(i).split("!!::!!").at(1);

            if(name != "lines"){
                continue;
            }

            // auto uri = QString("%1|layername = %2").arg(myVectorFileInfo.filePath()).arg(name);
            auto uri = QString("%1").arg(myVectorFileInfo.filePath());

            QgsVectorLayer * myVectorSubLayer = new QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, "ogr");  

            myVectorSubLayer->setSubLayerVisibility("points", false); 

            QgsProject::instance()->addMapLayer(myVectorSubLayer);

            //create a layerset
            QList<QgsMapLayer*> myList;

            myList.append(myVectorSubLayer);

            mpMapCanvas->setExtent(myVectorSubLayer->extent());

            // Set the Map Canvas Layer Set
            mpMapCanvas->setLayers(myList);
        }
        return;
    }
    else{
        qDebug("Layer is NOT valid");
        return;
    }
}
```